# Fully automatic Windows Deploy with WDS

Tags: windows-server-2008, wds

I've got a computer, that I can install Win2008 on. But I want to do it fully automatically and thru the network. I of course prepared unattended install and it works, although i still have to make few clicks(select installer language, select edition of windows, etc.). Is it possible to eliminate them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT). It can automate deployments of server and desktop operating systems. You can make it as automated as you like.

[Microsoft MDT](http://www.microsoft.com/mdt)

Comment: MDT is probably the way to go, the learning curve can be quite steep though.